# Struggling to patch a record in mongodb, unique not working and req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm learning node.js and it's amazing, especially with mongo, but sometimes I struggle to solve a simple problem, like patching only 1 attribute in my user database.

It's easier to patch something that cannot be unique, but I want to patch an username attribute and I defined it as "unique" in my schema. I don't know why, but MongoDB doesn't care other db entry has the same user, it let me save.

My schema:

```
/** @format */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    userNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isSubscriber: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDisabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    acceptedTerms: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

On my user controllers in node, I want to updateOne({ _id: userId}, { username: myNewUsername} but it always happens, it doesn't take into consideration another db entry can have the username, so I tried a different strategy but it doesn't work:

```
exports.changeUsername = (req, res, next) => {
  // Requirements
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  const newUsername = req.body.username;

  console.log('userId: ' + userId);
  console.log('newUsername: ' + req.body.username);

  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.username) {
        const error = new Error('Could not find this sport');
        error.code = 'DUPLICATED';
        throw error;
      }
      return;
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));

  // if no username was in use then updateOne
  User.updateOne({ _id: userId }, { username: newUsername })
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'username has been updated',
        username: result.username,
      });
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

I don't know if I can updateOne at the same time add some find validation. What I am doing wrong? Users cannot have the same username.

On the console, it seems it works, but it throws an extra error I don't understand:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/username/Sites/pipi-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:776:10)
```

I tried this other approach and it works, but doesn't trigger an error if the record is not unique as I stated in the schema.

```
// GET ONLY ONE SPORT BY ID
exports.changeUsername = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Requirements
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  const newUsername = req.body.username;

  console.log('userId: ' + userId);
  console.log('newUsername: ' + req.body.username);

  try {
    const oldUsername = await User.findOne({ username: newUsername });

    if (oldUsername.username) {
       throw new Error('Error: its duplicated');
    }

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { username: newUsername },
      { new: true }
    );
    console.log('User successfully updated.');
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, user });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
};
```

If I uncomment the code above, it triggers an error if I find a record on the database that matches but it doesn't allow me to continue to my next line of codes I the username is not found on the db.

I get a new error:

```
userId: 6231bdef334afbde85ed9f43
newUsername: tetete
ERROR:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username')
    at exports.changeUsername (/Users/user/Sites/pipi-api/v1/controllers/users/index.js:43:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is not related to Mongo. It means that you are trying to send a response and the response is already sent.

The issue is because you called both `User.findOne` and `User.updateOne` and both of them has `.then` handler. So the first one of these that finishes will send the actual response. In the moment the second one finished, the response is already send and the error is thrown because you are trying to send response again.

Mongo will throw the error if you try to change `username` property that some other user already have. You should check if the `req.params.userId` and `req.body.username` sent correctly to the backend. Try to `console.log()` them and check if they are maybe `null`.

Consider refactoring your handler to use async/await instead of `then/catch`. You can do it like this:

```js
exports.changeUsername = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    const newUsername = req.body.username;

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, { username: newUsername }, { new: true });

    console.log('User successfully updated.');
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, user });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you sent, it works, but it doesn't return an error if the record is duplicated already. It's like the unique: true of the schema doesn't work.